# How can I stop Slack bot from asking to link Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, slack, bot

Slack bot keeps asking to link my Google Drive account. `I couldn’t find that file in Google Drive. Do I have the correct Google Drive account information for you here?`

But I do not want to ever link my Google Drive account. How can I disable this functionality with my Slack bot?

Comment: why do you not want to link Google Drive?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably aware that you can disable or remove the app by visiting https://[YOUR_TEAM_NAME].slack.com/apps (search for app, will give option to disable/remove top right). But this **applies to the entire team** which may not be your intention.

Maybe you can create a throw-away google account you don't use for anything else just so it stops asking you?

Comment: You are correct. My intention is to disable it for me and not the whole team.

Answer (score 1):

You can DM the "@Google Drive to Slack" user with the message "off". I verified with Slack customer support.